# Most elegant way to organize a List of Objects to a comprehensive Table?

Tags: r, compare

I'm somewhat a beginner in R and I did thought about some strategies how to tackle this (see below). I keep running into dead ends however.
Probably someone of you knows a more elegant way.

I'm presented with a fair bit of data that is basically structured like this (made up to illustrate the point):

```
Banana: Green, Yellow, Orange
Apple: Green, Red
Raspberry: Red, Yellow
```

I want this data to be presented in a matrix like this:

```
          Green Yellow Orange Red
Banana    TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
Apple     TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
Raspberry FALSE TRUE   FALSE  TRUE
```

Basically an overview where the information is presented a bit easier to digest (true and false can be substituted by just an "x" and blank, graphically, etc).

Now for what I tried: Put the data into a csv, imported into a dataframe in R. Extracted all unique values (colors) and all fruits, made a new data set out of it that resembles the table. But here I am stuck - I tried a lot of things but it just keeps getting more complicated. Maybe i'm missing out on a library that does the task?

Comment: Can you share the code you already tried?

Comment: After you import the data into R can you provide reproducible example of your data using `dput` so that we can use it? Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269